# Как выполнять команды в диспетчере пакетов в visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Ввожу команду, например, get-help NuGet, нажимаю Enter, просто перехожу на новую строку. Пробовал несколько команд. Видимо, не на Enter нужно нажимать, подскажите, на какую кнопку.

Answer (score 0):

Перезапуск visual studio помог